# $.post syntax in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please let me know if below is the correct way to send data to another page using jQuery or not. I am a beginner and not sure about the syntax. `rowData` is in JSON format. I am passing the values on click of a button.

```
$.post("GridValues.jsp", {"rowData": rowData });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

Comment: The question should probably rather be: "How do I interpret the API documentation".

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jquery call should work fine for you. Plus you can always refer the jquery API [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

> jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [,
>   dataType] )
>
> urlA string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> dataA map or string that is sent to the server with the request.
>
> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)A callback function that is executed
>   if the request succeeds.
>
> dataTypeThe type of data expected from the server. Default:
>   Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

Try them out and let us know if you come across any problems.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the syntax in detail.

Comment: can you give a little example for set dataType:'json' using $.post ?

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for your `POST` depends on whether the JSP page is expecting to receive CGI-style URI-encoded variables, or a JSON blob.

In the former (more common) case, your code is correct - the `rowData` variable will appear as a CGI parameter which will need to be JSON decoded.

If you wish to have your client code do something after the `$.post` call has completed then the *modern* way of doing that is to use deferred objects:

```
$.post(...).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // called on success
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // called on failure
}).always(function() {
    // called in both cases 
});
```

Note how using deferred objects exposes features (`.fail` and `.always` callbacks) that are not directly available using `$.post`, which only supports passing a `success` (aka `done`) handler.

Using the `jqXHR` *result* of `$.post` to register callbacks is more flexible than passing callbacks as parameters directly to the AJAX-related methods.  It allows you to write functions that are only responsible for *initiating* the AJAX call and then have handlers that are completely decoupled from that responsible for processing the results.

Comment: @JanDvorak the OP indicated that the `rowData` variable is already in JSON format.

Comment: noted and upvoted. Still, can you source the claim this is the preferred method?

Comment: @JanDvorak the deferred objects bit?  The edit I just added should help show that.  The other thing it does is make it really easy to decouple the async handlers from making the AJAX call.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post("GridValues.jsp", {"rowData": rowData }, function(){} );
```

it is same as

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "GridValues.jsp",
data: {"rowData": rowData },
success: function(){}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining and comparing it with original syntax.  It is easy for me now.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is valid.

See:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

the doc supplies this syntax:
`jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )`

Are you sure you don't want to include a success handler?